# `find` equivalent which supports .ignore files?

Tags: linux, bash, find, ignore

I frequently need to find files matching a certain name or type within a bundle of git repositories on my workstation. Some subdirectories within that bundle are only readable by root, though, so any invocation of `find` has the real results drowned out by the incessant stream of `find: './chroot/foo/bar/`...`: Permission denied`. I'm aware that this can be preempted with `-prune` or squelched with `2>/dev/null`, but what I'd really like is to be able to set a file with various literals and regexen (like a `.gitignore` file) and have anything matching a line from that file skipped. Ideally, this would only affect searches done within a subtree of the "`.ignore`" file's location, but that's a nice-to-have, not a must.

For grep-equivalent, this is possible with ripgrep/`rg`. I expect it can't be done with the standard-issue `find`, but is there a similar tool which will do it?

Note: I have also considered redefining `find` to mean `builtin find -path './chroot/' -prune -or $@`, but there are multiple distinct repository bundles where I need this and it would be hard to set up that alias without collateral damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fdfind`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/fd-find/fdfind.1.en.html) will respect `.ignore`, `.gitginore` and `.fdignore` files by default:

```
       -I, --no-ignore
              Show search results from files and directories that would otherwise be ignored by .gitignore, .ignore or .fdignore files.
```

Beyond that you can specify a custom ignore files:

```
       --ignore-file path
              Add a custom ignore-file in '.gitignore' format.  These files have a low precedence.
```

Don't forget to add `alias fd='fdfind'` to your `.bashrc`

Comment: Fantastic, that looks like exactly what I wanted! Going to check it works how I expect before I hit accept, but thanks much already.

Comment: Yep this does exactly what I want. Thanks. (I'm actually going with `alias fn=`, since this is closest to being `find -name`.)

Comment: Glad to hear. `fd` would have the advantage that BASH completion would work, too - at least under Debian'ish distros (https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/fd-find/filelist).